# Check if iterable has only one type of elements

Tags: python

I would like to implement a function that is going to return a boolean value based on whether the given iterable is "composed" only by elements of the same type.

For example [1, 'a'] is going to return False , [1,2,3,4] is going to return True

This is what I implement:

```
from typing import Iterable 
def has_one_datatype(it: Iterable) -> bool:
    distinct_elements_types = {type(el) for el in it}
    try:
        assert len(distinct_elements_types) == 1
    Except AssertionError:
        return False
    return True
```

This it seems to me very redundant as if I have 1000 elements of the same type it will calculate `type()` function 1000 times for nothing

Is there any more efficient way to implement it?

Comment: Also odd to use try/except here when you can just return `len(distinct_elements_types) == 1`

Comment: Note that not all iterables are finite, but you probably want https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all. Unlike your implementation that's lazy, so if e.g. the first two mismatch types the rest get ignored.

Comment: If you want to check every element, then you have to check every element.

Comment: I think that’s the point @JaredSmith - you don’t need to check every element.  You can stop at the first one that’s different.

Comment: @Mark yes sorry, should have been more specific that you need to check every element in the worst-case where they are actually all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Short circuit with `all` comparing against the type of the first element:

```
def has_one_datatype(it: Iterable) -> bool:
    it = iter(it)  # if not an iterator already
    t = type(next(it))
    return all(isinstance(x, t) for x in it)
```

This is short for:

```
def has_one_datatype(it: Iterable) -> bool:
    it = iter(it)
    t = type(next(it))
    for x in it:
        if not isinstance(x, t):
            return False
    return True
```

You could use `type(x) == t` instead of `isinstance(x, t)` if you don't want to allow subtypes with the random assumption that the first one has the most general type.

Comment: what is the advantage of this implementation? Why it is better than mine?

Comment: Nope, only in the worst case when all are actually the same. It will stop at the first mismatch.

Comment: Iif it finds 2 different types it will immediately stop and return `False` - but it will do all 1000 if they're all the same. This is unavoidable - if you want to know everything is the same you have to check

Comment: @GarbageTime As the answer states, it short-circuits, meaning it stops at the first mismatch. The worst case will always require to check them all.

Comment: `has_one_datatype` is (not so) subtlely different from the OP's code, which will return `False` for `[1, True]`, while yours will return `True`.

Comment: @chepner Hence my last remark. Mine will return `False` for `[True, 1]` which shows the randomness of basing isinstance on the frist element.